# IdentityServer 3 securing webAPI with User Informatioin

Tags: identityserver3

We have a need to secure our .net web api using open id and OAuth standards.  IdentityServer 3 is perfect for us as we have to use our existing user store.

Edited for more clarity:
Our company services multiple customers.  Each of our customers have their own database.  In our home grown client application when a customer user enters their user/password, we do a lookup to authenticate and that also determines what backend database the app connects to.

We now have a need to allow a couple of trusted partners to access our database resource for specific needs.  We have created a web api for them to make specific calls.  The web api needs to know what customer the partner is making the call for.  The partner is calling the api from services on their side so there is no user interaction.

I am trying to determine the flow to use to accomplish this.  I found some pretty good info on flows at https://gist.github.com/jawadatgithub/638c11f08ecc0d76b05c.

If I define the client using the Client Credentials flow, I don't know how for them to pass the customer they are making the calls on behalf of.  I don't think we want to definate a "Client" for every partner/customer combination, but is this the correct way?

What we had thought of initially is to give an additional user/password or secret key that would tell us the customer, but I am not sure what "flow" for the client would allow this.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this helps anyone else, we decided to go with a Hybrid flow for these types of requests.  We considered designating a service account (user/pw) for each of our customer databases that would give this trusted 3rd part access to them by requesting tokens with the Resource Owner Password Credential flow, but decided against it.  We decided against it for all the reasons the standards say not to use it for this use.

If the 3rd party wants to interact with us on the behalf of one of our customers, then they will need to build the UI on their side to redirect to us for user/pw authentication and consent.